# Is the JIT Compiler going to optimize local variables

Tags: java, jvm

Will the Java JIT Compiler optimize this code:

```
Class2 method() {
     Class foo = new Class();
     Class2 bar = new Class2();

     if (foo.variable == null)
        throw new RuntimeException();

     bar.otherVariable = 5;
     return bar;
}
```

By doing this:

```
Class2 method() {
     Class foo = new Class();

     if (foo.variable == null)
        throw new RuntimeException();

     Class2 bar = new Class2();
     bar.otherVariable = 5;

     return bar;
}
```

It is optimization of memory usage. When Class2 will be created and its memory allocated?

Comment: Why rely on the compiler? Often the best course of action is simply to write the optimised version yourself

Comment: the first version seems to be more readable for me, i mean by that putting all variables at the beginning and then all statements

Comment: The two snippets are not equivalent since the `Class2` constructor could have side effects. So moving it could change the behaviour and therefore JIT will not do it (unless it is really smart).

Comment: Oh you're right. Probably assuming that it is default constructor won't change anything ?

Comment: Theoretically JIT Compiler does more advanced optimizations than this. It can find whether it has side effects or not

Comment: Mind that the allocation of the `Class2` instance may fail with an `OutOfMemoryError` that must take place before the `if (foo.variable == null) throw new RuntimeException();`. In this specific case, it might be possible to pretend that the allocation always succeeds and the constructor always ran when the `RuntimeException` is thrown, but this not only requires the constructor to be side-effect free, but also free of any possibility to throw an exception or error.

Comment: If “putting all variables at the beginning” feels cleaner to you, why not simply use `Class foo = new Class(); Class2 bar; if(foo.variable == null) throw new RuntimeException(); bar = new Class2(); bar.otherVariable = 5; return bar;`. By the way, talking of clean code, `Class2` should have a suitable constructor instead of requiring outside code assigning `otherVariable`. Then, the code would look like `Class foo = new Class(); if(foo.variable == null) throw new RuntimeException(); return new Class2(5);` and the entire problem is solved, all variables at the beginning and lazily constructed.

Comment: Thank you all for answers. I know about the constructor. Setter is simplified case used just to clearly describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as with most things, is 'it depends'.

Firstly, the Java compiler won't do that re-ordering for you. The bytecode will be as you laid out.

Secondly, the JIT will be called when this has been called repeatedly. Until it's gone through multiple (10,000) executions, it's not going through the high level JIT compilation.

It's possible if you call this repeatedly with the field always being passed in as null, then it will optimise the function to drop the rest of the code which in turn will perform dead code elimination and elide the construction.

On the other hand, if the class you have performs some visible side effect (e.g. setting a global system property, creating a thread, assigning a static value) then the code won't be elided completely. It might in-line the object creation and effectively replace that constructor in place.

However, it's probably worth noting that even if the JIT doesn't optimise it away, creating a new instance which is then immediately available for GC is a fantastically cheap operation. Allocation is a bump pointer for a memory array and while there might be some field initialisation occurring, it will be in memory that's almost certainly hot in the cache and take up a trivial amount of time. When this method returns the class will be eligible for GC and can just be dropped (assuming no finalizers etc.)

Comment: `10_000` executions is just a myth that would not die anymore.

Comment: C1 won’t optimise out the construction of the object; you would need to get to C2 which is going to be the minimum of CompileThreshold (if not using tiered compilation) or Tier4CompileThreshold (if using tiered compilation) — And those are minimums, because after that the code gets out into a queue for subsequent compilation and installation, so you could easily be a few hundred/thousand calls further on. Not sure why you think that’s a myth when the JVM will tell you in the compilation logs.